# I don't remember editing this question, yet it shows like I am the editor

Tags: support

Going through my SE network activity, I found out [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22824276/274579), where I appear to [revise the question content](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22824276/revisions)s. However, I do not remember ever seeing this question, let alone editing it. It is not my subject of knowledge/interest anyway, and the edit itself is just partially correct, judging from the edit history. Moreover, the edit comment is just not my style of English (and has its own punctuation/capitalization problems).

How did this get into my list?

The only explanation I could find is that I accidentally approved a pending edit. If this is the case, why isn't the original editor in the list?

Answer (score 7):

You did choose the edit action in [this suggested-edit in the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4486333) which makes you the editor instead of the user that proposed the edit.